# R: Adding Labels to a Bubble Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I found this really good tutorial that shows how to make Bubble Plots using the ggplot library: https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/bubble.html:

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggrepel)
library(plotly)

# The dataset is provided in the gapminder library
library(gapminder)
data <- gapminder %>% filter(year=="2007") %>% dplyr::select(-year)

# Prepare data
tmp <- data %>%
 mutate(
   annotation = case_when(
    gdpPercap > 5000 & lifeExp < 60 ~ "yes",
    lifeExp < 30 ~ "yes",
     gdpPercap > 40000 ~ "yes"
    )
) %>%
mutate(pop=pop/1000000) %>%
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country))


 
    # Plot
   my_plot = ggplot( tmp, aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent)) +
        geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
        scale_size(range = c(1.4, 19), name="Population (M)") +
        scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
        theme_ipsum() +
        theme(legend.position="none") +
        geom_text_repel(data=tmp %>% filter(annotation=="yes"), aes(label=country), size=4 )
```

[image]

I would like to make this into an interactive plotly plot, but keep some the labels/captions. I tried to do this with the "ggplotly" function:

```
ggplotly(my_plot)
```

[image]

**But as we can see here, the labels (e.g. South Africa, USA) have disappeared! Is there a way to restore these labels and keep the plot as an interactive plot?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523130/how-to-add-value-labels-in-ggplot-time-series/73523743#73523743) with similar issue.

As per warning message:

> geom_GeomTextRepel() has yet to be implemented in plotly

To work around that you can use `geom_text` instead and play with the *y/x* values:

```
my_plot = ggplot( tmp, aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
  scale_size(range = c(1.4, 19), name="Population (M)") +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  geom_text(data=tmp %>% filter(annotation=="yes"), aes(y=lifeExp-1.5, label=country), size=4 )

ggplotly(my_plot)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bushidov: Thank you so much for your answer! Two questions I had:

Comment: 1) When I try to save this file (e.g. htmltools::save_html(html = my_plot, file = "my_plot.html") ) ... the plot looks "squished". Is there any way to save it as a regular sized html plot?

Comment: 2) Is there any way to add the name of the country in the hover text as well? Thank you so much for everything!